# counter widget for html flash single url

Tags: html, widget, counter

anyone know of a good counter widget that will integrate easy and free into HTML? Its to try and build a flash page with something saying "limited time offer..."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many available online for free - just Google 'free counter HTML'. Here is a decent one:

http://www.easycounter.com/FreeCounter3.html

Hope this helps!
Zach